# how long should I wait to hear back?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, job-offer, human-resources, follow-up

I went to a job interview for a factory. (This is going to get confusing so bare with me) I applied for a machine operator, and they interviewed me for a line worker. Well after looking over my resume the superintendent saw how much Manager experience I have and suggested I apply for the superintendent position saying I was overqualified and over dressed for the position in which I was being interviewed, but I could have the job if I so wished but I wouldn't be able to get the superintendent position, and he wasn't able to interview me for a position equal to his (Obviously). So I submitted an application for the superintendent position and have been waiting. I waited about 3 days and then I called to get some feedback but was sent to voicemail. I left a message with my number to call me back but never received a call back. A few days later I called again and got the same voicemail, so instead of leaving a message I decided to stop by the factory. How ever nobody in personnel was able to give me any information on what would happen just simply stating I would receive a call. Yesterday was Christmas and it has been over a week that I've been waiting for this call. What should I do? Should I go back and ask for the lower grade position? I've submitted applications to other companies but nothing seems as promising. Or should I wait? I'm very anxious to get this job and I want it so badly. I do not want to bug but I am very confused. Would they give me a call back to let me know they are not interested?

Comment: You may want to contact their HR to find out if they do have a superintendent position open or not. Either send an e-mail a phone call.

Comment: Also, this is holiday season. Don't expect prompt answer.

Comment: You seem to have the "following up" part down pat but that may be too much of a good thing. Don't pile up the calls - they'll remember you but not in a good way. At some point, you are going to get obtrusive.

Comment: A week is nothing. It can take months to fill a position.

Answer (score 2):

There are several questions you should ask yourself:

1. If the company is this disorganized, do you really want to work there? Maybe it is only their HR department, but normally this is a symptom of a company-wide culture, in this case not a good one.
2. If you take the line worker position, how much patience do you have to wait for a promotion to the superintendent position? It is not the worst start if you first get to know the company from the position of a line worker. However, if they are disorganized I wonder how well they do in promoting the right people internally.
3. How desperate are you to join this company?
4. What are your other options?

Since probably the key people are on vacation until early January, I am afraid you will need another week of patience at least. Also keep in mind that the suggestion you should apply for the superintendent position was just the opinion of one manager. Probably other people in the company see things differently.

You didn't say much about questions 3 and 4, but they are the key to deciding what to do (settle for line worker or insist on the superintendent position) and how much time to give them for a proper response.

Comment: We are fairly sure of the position being available. My brother-in-law saw an online posting for the position along with a couple people verifying the position was open.

Comment: also the manager that interviewed me was also a superintendent and said he started at line workers position and it took him 8 years to be promoted.